# Shouldn't changing a user's Drupal locale also change $user->timezone?

Tags: drupal, timezone

I must be missing something really obvious here:

I have a user whose locale is set to America/Los Angeles.  When I look in the 'users' database table, they have a value of -28800 for the timezone field.  This makes sense; 8 hours before GMT = -28800 seconds.

But now, when the user changes his locale to America/New York, the value of timezone stays the same, rather than switching to -18000, 5 hours before GMT.  Why isn't this change happening?  If I'm looking in the wrong place, where would I find a timezone value that matches their locale?

The server's timezone is also set to America/Los Angeles, if that matters.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug. What version of Drupal? Either way, you should be able to fix it fairly easily with hook_user. You'll need to do a user_save and explicitly define the new timezone value. It'd be something like this:

```
function trnAccount_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {

switch($op) {
case 'update':
  user_save($account, array('timezone' => $myTimeZone);
break;
}
```

$myTimeZone is a placeholder. Do a print_r on the incoming $edit within this hook and you should be able to find where the timezone change has been recorded then just replace $myTimeZone with that array path (for example... $edit['values']['timezone']). If its not coming through at all then something is wrong with the form you're using the change the locale.

If you're using a form you wrote yourself, you could also handle this in the submit function for that form.

Comment: Weirder and weirder. I'm running Drupal 6.19, if that matters. I'm going the route you suggested; inside the _user handler, I'm seeing two useful values in $edit: 'dst' is whatever was specified in the timezone dropdown (e.g., "America/Los_Angeles"), and 'timezone' is whatever the database says it is (e.g., -28800). When I try the user_save thing you suggested, passing in the offset value (e.g., -14400), I fall into a PHP error of "Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone ()'".

Comment: The same thing happens if I pass in "America/Los_Angeles".  And if I try simply bashing the new timezone value into the database, it's not there by the time the _user update handler is done. Blurgh.  Something seems really broken here, and I'm totally confused (especially about how something so basic could be broken like this).  I'm checking my code to see if I'm doing something wrong with the user account, but so far I'm seeing nothing.

Comment: Moving on for now, anyway -- I've put together a not-too-expensive function that will get the user's timezone offset from his $user->dst value, and will call that when I need the offset.  I'm worried that hardcore monkeying around with the value of $user->timezone is going to screw up something down in the bowels of Drupal (plus I can't get those changes to stick, anyway...).  But I'm still confused about why this is going on; I've posted this same thing over on the Drupal boards to no effect; maybe I'll try to push it up a bit.  But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ARGGH -- FALSE ALARM.  Just as I was wrapping all this up, I thought it might be worth checking another of my Drupal sites to see what happens with $user->timezone there.  Turns out that it's working correctly -- change the locale in the user edit page and $user->timezone changes as it ought to.  Thus, I'm screwing the pooch somewhere in my current site; Drupal itself seems to be OK.  Apologies for wasting your time; but many thanks in any case.

Comment: Double arggh.  In the interest of full disclosure, or good old fashioned Maoist self-criticism, my problem was that my site was running the Auto Time Zone module, which uses Javascript to check the user's browser for its current timezone and then sets the user's account accordingly.  I just forgot the module was installed; it's been a while....